# 48VDC to 240VAC daisy chain inverters

Tags: inverter, dc-ac

Is it possible to daisy chain smaller inverters to achieve a higher overall output power? For instance if I have a 48VDC battery bank and I want to power a large compressor at 240VAC it will need a lot of power. More then the inverters I have seen. So is it possible to connect inverters together to achieve the higher power in terms of KW?

Comment: You might want to change your title. Daisy-chain means that you're connecting the output from one to the input of the other, or at best, connecting them in series. That's not what you're asking here.

Comment: If you need more output power than the inverters you've seen can deliver you might want to check whether your 48V source can devliver that power at all.

Comment: There are inverters available that are designed to be linked together to increase the available running watts. As an example look up the model number: M12000L-48SP power inverter.

Answer (score 5):

Generally not.

Inverters generate AC. If inverters were to be paralleled they would need to be synchronised so that the AC was of identical frequency and phase. This isn't likely to be possible with the class of unit I suspect you are thinking of. (Generator sets require the same synchronisation but can be pulled into synch electro-mechanically.)

Note: KW = kelvin-watts which doesn't make any sense. kW = kilo-watts. Small 'k' for 'kilo' as defined in SI units.